# Error while using Salescloud objects in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am trying to leverage Salescloud and Service Cloud Events in my Journey Builder interaction. My Marketing cloud instance is already integrated with Salescloud. However when i am trying to Use Salesforce objects in my interaction i am getting the below error. Any suggestions to resolve this[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with Salesforce integration. Try uninstalling Marketing Cloud connector and re-install into your sales cloud org.

Comment: the issue was with Multi org configuration enabled in our marketing cloud instance. As of now JB do not supports Multi org configuration

Comment: This is a multi-org enabled account which allows each business unit to connect to a separate Salesforce Org via the V5 integration.In this case the enterprise and mid 7243126 were integrated to separate orgs which had the same name. There is a limitation with multi-org which prevents integrating to two orgs with the same name.The workaround in this case is to rename the Salesforce Org for the Sandbox (integrated at the BU) and then to re-save the integration at both the MID and EID levels.